# Action creator in Redux giving error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, reducers

I have a list of clients. When a new client is added, I want the action creator to check if the client name already exists, and if it does, to show an error. The filter() method I am using to find out if a client with that name already exists is not working ... what am I doing wrong?

action:

```
export const addClient = (client) => {
    return(dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log('state: ' + JSON.stringify(getState())); 
        let clientList = getState().clientList; 
        console.log('clientList: ' + clientList); 
        if (clientList && clientList.map( client => { 
            return client.name;
        }).includes(client.name)) 
            { return ( dispatch({type: 'ADD CLIENT ERROR'}) ) }
        else { dispatch({type: 'ADD CLIENT', client}) }
    }
}
```

reducer:

```
const initState = {
  clientList: [],
  clientErr: null,
};

const clientReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD CLIENT ERROR':
      console.log('add client failed');
      return {
        ...state,
        clientErr: 'A client with this exact name already exists, please try again.',
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default clientReducer;
```

The button to add the client works fine and the dispatch is sent to the action but that's where I get the error.

[image: console]

Comment: could you please show console.log(getState) of your action ?

Comment: ƒ getState() {
    if (isDispatching) {
      throw new Error('You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. ' + 'The reducer has already received the state as an argument. ' + 'Pas…

Comment: as you can see here getState() is a method, not an object

Comment: oh! so can I do getState().clientList.filter() ?

Comment: you could destructure clientList from object that getState() will return -> `const { clientList } = getState();` and then filter it in your if statement

Comment: I think my issue is that my initial clientList is empty. I get this error trying to add the very first client.

Comment: when I do this: const { clientList } = getState();
        console.log(clientList) , it logs undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change logic to find if name exist:

```
let clientList = getState().clientList
if (clientList && clientList.map( client => {
      return client.name;
    }).includes(client.name)
   )
```

Comment: I didn't know includes() is a method, that's cool. But viciousP helped me realize above that getState is actually a method, getState() so I still get the error using this, map is undefined.

Comment: let clientList = getState().clientList;
if (clientList && clientList.map( client => {
      return client.name;
    }).includes(client.name)
   )

Comment: I just edited my code above and included your snippet. I don't receive an error anymore, however the error does not log. It still adds the new client even though one with the same name already exists

Comment: See console.log outputs to find the problem
console.log('state: ' + JSON.stringify(getState());
let clientList = getState().clientList; 
console.log('clientList: ' + clientList);
        if (clientList && clientList.map( client => { return client.name; }).includes(client.name) )  {
return (
            dispatch({type: 'ADD CLIENT ERROR'})
            )
}
        else {
            dispatch({type: 'ADD CLIENT', client})
        }

Comment: you should go with clients.clientsList

Answer (score 1):

getState is a Redux method and here you're trying to access object property by dot notation. What you can do here is to destructure value returned from this method like this:

```
const {
  clients: { clientsList },
} = getState();
```

and then filter it in your if statement.

Comment: This works for the most part but there is a bug somewhere in my code. When I put in a client name and add it, it adds the client. Then, when I do the same client name back to back it still adds it, however if I do it a third time in a row, it says add client failed. So it works only after the third time the same name is added.

Comment: I think it is because the first time it adds the name, but the second time the name === null so it doesn't read it as already existing. Why is it null the second time?

Comment: got it to work! wish I can give both check marks but I will give to him since he gave me more code to work with. Couldn't have done it without yours though, thank you!

Comment: Good to hear that it is working :) Hope you learned something about debugging here